# OPNET Compilation Error

Tags: windows, networking, testing, opnet

I recently installed OPNET 14 and i have been unable to run simulations. I keep getting the error below when i try to run any:

```
<<< Recoverable Error >>>
Object repository construction failed
due to errors encountered by the binder program (bind_so_msvc)
T (0), EV (-), MOD (NONE), PROC (sim_load_repos_rebuild)
----
Errors reported by the binder program follow
(these messages have been saved in (C:\Users\Karl\op_admin\tmp\bind_err_7640):
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'kernel32.lib'


----
<<< Program Abort >>>
Error encountered rebuilding repository -- unable to proceed
T (0), EV (-), MOD (NONE), PROC (sim_load_repos_load)

----
```

Kindly advise on how i can over come this.
Appreciate the help.

Comment: What version of visual studio do you installed? Are you sure that the environement variables configurations are OK? check this: http://faisal-howinstallopnet14inwindowsxp.blogspot.fr/

Answer (score 5):

1. Select Edit --> Preferences
2. Type "network sim" in the search for field
3. Click  the value field of Network Simulation Repositories
4. Add stdmod to the value field of Network Simulation Repositories